# Using pivot_longer in R in Kaggle, producing NAs for second half of data

Tags: r, pivot, na, long-integer, kaggle

Here is the data frame that I started with.

[image]
I tried to change it from wide to long using this code:

```
#change data frame from wide to long
us_population_v3 <- pivot_longer(us_population_v2, cols = !1, names_to = "year", values_to = "total_population")
View(us_population_v3)
```

It created a new data frame, but the second half of the data is missing. I'm not sure why or how to fix it. This is part of what it produced. The first half looks correct, but the second half is NA and says "exported on..."

[image]

I tried turning the data frame from wide to long. I'm not sure what to try from here.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of running `dput(us_population_v2[1:4, 1:4])`? That will create code we can use to recreate a portion of your data that we can test potential solutions on.

Comment: On the face of it, your output doesn't look like it would come from the sample data you provided (e.g. where did the "Exported on.." come from?) so some clarification and reproducible data as code would help.

Comment: structure(list(Years = c("Resident Population (People)", "    Age", 
"        Under 5 years of age (People)", "        5 to 14 years (People)"
), X1945 = c(139928165L, NA, 12978811L, 21598930L), X1946 = c(141388566L, 
NA, 13243923L, 21843913L), X1947 = c(144126071L, NA, 14405735L, 
22257249L)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: This is the output I received. I'm very new to this, so thank you for your help.

Comment: I suspect that the NAs correspond to rows in your data that are blank -- e.g. there's probably a final row where the "Years" column says "Exported on: 02/06/2024" with blanks in the other columns. I also suspect that by "second half" you actually mean "the last 53 rows or so," ie the ones that were produced from that trailing "Exported on" line. You should probably just filter out the data that isn't there, e.g. `|> filter(!is.na(total_population)` or `|> filter(stringr::str_detect(Years, "Exported on", negate = TRUE))`